# why nothing shows up in my output file, it comes out to be blank?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace WordFreq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fullReview = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Reviews.txt").ToLower();
            string[] stripChars = { ";", ",", ".", "-", "_", "^", "(", ")", "[", "]",
                                    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                                    "9", "\n", "\t", "\r","<",">" };
            foreach (string character in stripChars)
            {
                fullReview = fullReview.Replace(character, "");
            }

            // Split on spaces into a List of strings
            List<string> wordList = fullReview.Split(' ').ToList();

            // Define and remove stopwords
            string[] stopwords = new string[] {"a", "about", "above", "after", "again",
                                               "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any",
                                               "are", "aren't", "as","at", "be", "because",
                                               "been", "before", "being", "below", "between",
                                               "both", "but", "by", "can't", "cannot",
                                               "could", "couldn't", "did", "didn't", "do",
                                               "does", "doesn't", "doing", "don't", "down",
                                               "during", "each", "few", "for", "from",
                                               "further", "had", "hadn't", "has", "hasn't",
                                               "have", "haven't", "having", "he", "he'd",
                                               "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's",
                                               "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his",
                                               "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm",
                                               "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "isn't",
                                               "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's",
                                               "me", "more", "most", "mustn't", "my",
                                               "myself", "no", "nor", "not", "of", "off",
                                               "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought",
                                               "our", "ours ", " ourselves", "out", "over",
                                               "own", "same", "shan't", "she", "she'd",
                                               "she'll", "she's", "should", "shouldn't", "so",
                                               "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's",
                                               "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves",
                                               "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they",
                                               "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've",
                                               "this", "those", "through", "to", "too",
                                               "under", "until", "up", "very", "was",
                                               "wasn't", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're",
                                               "we've", "were", "weren't", "what", "what's",
                                               "when", "when's", "where", "where's",
                                               "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom",
                                               "why", "why's", "with", "won't", "would",
                                               "wouldn't", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", 
                                               "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself",
                                               "yourselves" };
            foreach (string word in stopwords)
            {
                // While there's still an instance of a stopword in the wordList, remove it.
                // If we don't use a while loop on this each call to Remove simply removes a single
                // instance of the stopword from our wordList, and we can't call Replace on the
                // entire string (as opposed to the individual words in the string) as it's
                // too indiscriminate (i.e. removing 'and' will turn words like 'bandage' into 'bdage'!)
                while (wordList.Contains(word))
                {
                    wordList.Remove(word);
                }
            }

            // Create a new Dictionary object
            Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            // Loop over all over the words in our wordList...
            foreach (string word in wordList)
            {
                // If the length of the word is at least three letters...
                if (word.Length >= 2)
                {
                    // ...check if the dictionary already has the word.
                    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
                    {
                        // If we already have the word in the dictionary, increment the count of how many times it appears
                        dictionary[word]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Otherwise, if it's a new word then add it to the dictionary with an initial count of 1
                        dictionary[word] = 1;
                    }
                } // End of word length check
            } // End of loop over each word in our input

            // Create a dictionary sorted by value (i.e. how many times a word occurs)
            var sortedDict = (from entry 
                                in dictionary 
                           orderby entry.Value descending 
                            select entry).ToDictionary(KeyValuePair => KeyValuePair.Key,
                                                       KeyValuePair => KeyValuePair.Value);

            // Loop through the sorted dictionary and output the top 10 most frequently occurring words
            int count = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("---- Most Frequent Terms in the File: " +fullReview+ " ----");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> KeyValuePair in sortedDict)
            {
                // Output the most frequently occurring words and the associated word counts
                Console.WriteLine(count + "\t" + KeyValuePair.Key + "\t" + KeyValuePair.Value);
                count++;

                // Only display the top 10 words then break out of the loop!
            }

            using (StreamWriter streamWrite = new StreamWriter("C:\\output.txt"))
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> KeyValuePair in dictionary)
            {
                streamWrite.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", KeyValuePair.Key, KeyValuePair.Value);
            }

            // Wait for the user to press a key before exiting
        } // End of Main method
    } // End of Program class
} // End of namespace
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

First please take a look at the links Remus suggested in the comments.

Secondly, your code should work, the only thing that's probably wrong here is that you're trying to write directly onto `C:\`. Try to place it under a directory such as `C:\Temp\` and you should be good to go.

Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/342276/cannot-save-in-hard-disk-drive-c) for some more info about why that happens.

Comment: I tried to do that but still isn't working, could you please tell me in which format should I store my text file in C drive, as a ANS 2 or UTP 8 text file

Comment: @user3553357 .txt is fine. What error are you getting if any? Have you tried running your code in a separate clean solution? It works.

Comment: Ya I tried to run it, it does work and doesn't give me any errors but when I see my output file, it comes out to be blank

Answer (score 0):

Omri Aharon is right - I just ran your code and it did work!!! once I changed it to a directory that IS NOT C:\

C:\temp worked for me for reading and writing

Comment: I tried to do that but still isn't working, could you please tell me in which format should I store my text file in C drive, as a ANS 2 or UTP 8 file